# Unity not able to find package listed in their own tutorial

Tags: unity, macos

**Please note:** I uploaded a [Youtube video here that may help tie all my confusion together](https://youtu.be/SQCYHXNLrvg) but I also explain the highlights below which forms the basis of my question.

---

Unity here. I'm trying to follow their first basic tutorial and am at the ["*Before you begin*"](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/main-character-and-first-script?uv=2020.3&projectId=5c6166dbedbc2a0021b1bc7c#61680d60edbc2a021f308fa5) section where the fifth bullet down says:

> "*5. Install the 2D Tilemap Editor package for your project.*"

The link provided in that bullet [takes you here](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/project-setup-processes#60ed7a86edbc2a002520b6f4). *That* page tells you to go to `Window >> Package Manager` and lookup the 2D Tilemap Editor package.

When I go to `Window >> Package Manager` I see:

[image]

If I click on the search bar in the top right corner and search for "2D" or "Tile" or "Editor" nothing shows up.

**Does anybody know how I can search for and import this 2D Tilemap Editor package?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't say I didn't have the same problem! Just change the "Packages" dropdown to "Unity Registry" instead of "My Assets", as it will only search in your downloaded packages in this mode.

[image: Screenshot showing drop-down selection]

Comment: Holy smokes that was it! Thank you x1000!

Comment: I thought my assets refers to the one you bought/ added from the asset store and not only the downloaded ones.

Answer (score 2):

A little addition for future readers: if the accepted answer still doesn't solve the problem, probably this package is a preview. You can enable preview packages in the package manager.

[image]